# Weblogic and Spring Boot com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat$Value.hasLenient()Z method doesn't exist

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, weblogic

I have a dependency on jakson-annotation inside version 2.10.3. And everything worked fine, but suddenly I have a clash between dependency and Weblogic third-party library when I try to deploy an application. Version on Weblogic is obviously 2.7.9.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:
    com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.JSR310DateTimeDeserializerBase.createContextual(JSR310DateTimeDeserializerBase.java:104)

The following method did not exist:

com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat$Value.hasLenient()Z

The method's class, com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat$Value, is available from the following locations:

jar:file:/C:/.../Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/oracle_common/modules/thirdparty/jackson-annotations-2.7.9.jar!/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat$Value.class
zip:C:/.../Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/my_app_war/jixshv/war/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-annotations-2.10.3.jar!/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat$Value.class

It was loaded from the following location:

file:/C:/.../Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/oracle_common/modules/thirdparty/jackson-annotations-2.7.9.jar
```

Ok, it is caused because spring boot 2.2.0+ use 2.10.0 which has this method.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is in weblogic.xml:

```
-src
  |--main
  |    |--java
  |    |--resources
  |    |--webapp
             |--WEB-INF
                   |--weblogic.xml
```

and inside weblogic.xml:

```
<prefer-application-packages>
  ...
  <package-name>...</package-name>
  <package-name>com.fasterxml.*</package-name>
  <package-name>...</package-name>
  ...
</prefer-application-packages>
```